# Whats-Meta page for Stack Overflow should explain Stack Exchange Meta

Tags: discussion

Why does the [help/whats-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page for Stack Overflow make no mention of the [Stack Exchange Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Everyone agrees there is ambiguity in the use of dual Meta sites (local and SE).  Wouldn't `/help/whats-meta` be an obvious place to offer clarification and a link?

The SE site is linked in the ubiquitous top-left menu, and that's all.

Comment: Am I somehow not a part of "everyone"? I think there is little to no ambiguity surrounding the fact that all Stack Exchange sites have child metas, including http://stackexchange.com

Comment: Post-question:  Is it good form to delete this post because it has no support, or should it remain because somehow it is informative on a lesser level?

Comment: The question is a valid question that has valid answers. The community does not currently agree with the premise, but that doesn't make it off-topic. If you delete this, no one else can see that it has already been asked, and we cannot close future questions on the same topic as a duplicate of this. If you would like to be disassociated from this content, you can flag it for moderator attention detailing that and why.

Answer (score 3):

Why should it?  Meta Stack Exchange [has its *own* page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) to explain what that meta is about.  The only ambiguity that exists is that MSE is meant for all of the network sites, whereas per-site Metas (including Stack Overflow) are *only* meant to concern that site.

(There *might* be a typo there in that the uber-Meta still refers to Stack Overflow in parts, but once that's fixed, there's really no issue...)

Comment: Is there a problem with posts on the per-site Meta that belong on MSE?  Perhaps after this `whats-meta` page is viewed?

Comment: @Smandoli:  Anything that really does apply to the uber-Meta gets migrated, and vice-versa.

Comment: `Anything that really does apply to the uber-Meta gets migrated, and vice-versa` -- It seems to me that comment is more relevant as an answer to my question.  "It doesn't matter, everything is sorted out as it appears."

Comment: @Smandoli bug reports and feature requests can be posted on whatever meta the poster feels most comfortable posting them. If they need to be moved, they can be moved.

Answer (score 0):

No, it really shouldn't. Anyone who needs to read a page in the Help Center on SO/MSO about what MSE is for *doesn't need to know what MSE is for*. All normal support questions, discussions, and even many feature requests and bug reports can and should be handled here first. Only questions that are intended to or can only apply to *all* SE sites should be asked on MSE. And only those interested in the way *all* the sites work should visit MSE much.

SE employees can see all [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions on all per-site metas (including, obviously, this one), and regularly check for them, so even if a request turns out to need migration, that can be done easily and quickly.